# Can conclude that $N = f\left(K\right)\oplus f\left(L\right)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $K,L$ be two submodules of an $R$-module $M$ with the property that $K+L=M$ and $f:M\longrightarrow N$ is an $R$-epimorphism. Assume that $K \cap L = \ker f$.  Can conclude that $N = f\left(K\right)\oplus f\left(L\right)$  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious (from surjectivity) that $f(K)+f(L)=N$.

Now take $x\in f(K)\cap f(L)$. Then $x=f(y)=f(z)$ with $y\in K$ and $z\in L$. Since $y-z\in \ker f$ we get $y\in L$, so $y\in K\cap L$ and therefore $y\in\ker f$. Thus we get $x=f(y)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:**  $N = f(K) + f(L)$.

Certainly, $N \supseteq f(K) + f(L)$.  For the reverse containment, let $n \in N$.  As $f$ is surjective, there exists $m \in M$ such that $f(m) = n$.  Since $M = K + L$, there exist $k \in K$ and $\ell \in L$ such that $m = k + \ell$.  Now, $f(k) + f(\ell) = n$, demonstrating that $N \subseteq f(K) + f(L)$.

**Claim:**  $N = f(K) \oplus f(L)$.

Suppose that $f(k) + f(\ell) = 0$ for some $k \in K$ and $\ell \in L$.  Then, $f(k + \ell) = 0$, so $k + \ell \in \ker f = K \cap L$.  Now, $k = (k + \ell) - \ell \in L$, so $k \in K \cap L = \ker f$; hence, $f(k) = 0$.  Analogously, $\ell = (k + \ell) - k \in K$, so $\ell \in K \cap L = \ker f$; hence, $f(\ell) = 0$.